# Consulta MYSQL 2 tablas

Tags: mysql

Estoy trabajando con MYSQL y estoy intentando realizar una consulta a 2 tablas.
La primera tabla se llama *solicitud* y la segunda se llama *alumno*. Lo que estoy intentando realizar hasta ahora sin éxito, es extraer los ID de la tabla *solicitud* cuando se cumplan 2 condiciones: la primera es que la fecha de inicio de alguna solicitud coincida con el día actual y la segunda es validar que no haya registros de alumnos relacionados con dicha solicitud. Es decir, si no hay registros en la tabla *alumno* relacionados con alguna solicitud y si la fecha de inicio de alguna solicitud coincide con el día actual, entonces que muestre los ID de cada solicitud para identificar en donde no se ha ingresado información de usuarios aún.

Hasta ahora la consulta que tengo es la siguiente:

```
 SELECT f.id,
  IF(COUNT(a.id_alumno) > 0, 'SI', 'NO') AS EXISTE
 FROM solicitud f INNER JOIN alumno a ON f.id_solicitud=a.id_solicitud
 WHERE f.fecha_inicio = CURDATE() AND f.estado = 1
```

La tabla solicitud contiene los siguientes datos:

```
id_solicitud (PK autoincrement)
fecha_solicitud
fecha_inicio
id_usuario (FK)
estado
```

La tabla alumno contiene los siguientes campos:

```
id_alumno (PK autoincrement)
nombre
apellido
curso
id_solicitud (FK)
estado
```

La tabla *alumno* tiene una llave foránea *id_solicitud* relacionada con *id_solicitud* de tabla *solicitud*. Por lo tanto, una solicitud puede tener uno o varios alumnos asignados, así como también, un alumno puede pertenecer a varias solicitudes.

En esta consulta que tengo, por alguna razón solo me carga un registro, ya habiendo validado que existen más.

Comment: Si lográs resumir en una línea el problema en cuestión (colocándola como título), vas a captar mayor atención a tu pregunta.

Comment: Algo no me cuadra.. puede haber solicitudes sin usuario??? si es asi, la integridad referencial no sirve para nada....

Comment: No son usuarios de sistema, si te refieres a eso, es otro tipo de información que se vincula a las solicitudes.

Comment: no importa de que... yo leo esto "La tabla usuario tiene una llave foránea id relacionada con id de tabla solicitud." entonces... es una llave foranea o no??? o capaz no es obligatoria, con lo cual no es una llave foranea per se... es mas... sigo sin enteder.. meten numeros de usuarios que no existen??? quien mantiene la integridad referencial???

Comment: Hice un cambio en la pregunta, espero que con esto se aclare la confusión.

Comment: En lugar de `INNER` usa `LEFT`; observa cuando `u.id` es nulo. Nota que las FK tienen dirección.

Comment: Cambia por LEFT pero continua mostrando solo un registro.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar algunos datos de ejemplo, para poder reproducir lo que estás mencionando?

Comment: Agregue un ejemplo de lo que muestra la consulta.

Comment: ejemplo de datos de entrada y salida.. no somos magos, no sabemos si estan bien las cosas o no.. si haces un fiddle en algun lado , mucho mejor...

Comment: igual.. ahora que miro bien... no tiene ni sentido el join.. basta hacer la cuenta en la misma tabla.. toda esta consulta no tiene sentido.. siento que es un problema a-b... vos nos decis como lo queres solucionar, pero el problema es otro...

Comment: Como ya han señalado algunos, esto  no tiene ningún sentido. Por ejemplo, ¿qué significa la columna `id` en la tabla `alumnos`, la cual relacionas con la columna `id` de `solicitud`? ¿Acaso en cada alumno tienes una referencia a las solicitudes? ¿Cómo manejas el caso de un alumno con varias solicitudes? ¿Creas otra fila en la tabla alumnos, cayendo en una redundancia de datos espantosa? ¿Cómo explicas que pueda haber registros huérfanos? Es cierto que pueden haber solicitudes esperando a que sea asignadas a un alumno, pero eso implicaría un modelo de datos distinto al que describes.

Comment: Pensándolo así en frío, lo que más se parece a lo que intentas describir en tu pregunta sería una especie de tabla de **solicitudes futuras** que esperan a que sean asignadas a algún alumno. Esas solicitudes, cuando un alumno las selecciona, deberán desaparecer de **solicitudes futuras** y pasar a una tabla de **solicitudes asignadas**, teniendo esta última tabla una relación de llave foránea que implique al alumno o los alumnos a los que se le asignó. En ese caso, **en solicitudes futuras estarán siempre todas las solicitudes pendientes y puedes consultar a esa tabla directamente.**

Comment: Agregue unos cambios en las consultas y también agregue la estructura de las tablas, espero que ahora se entienda de mejor manera mi problema.

Comment: Aca hay errores de concepto groseros... o sea.. "Por lo tanto, una solicitud puede tener uno o varios alumnos asignados, así como también, un alumno puede pertenecer a varias solicitudes." si esto es asi, deberia existir una tabla intermedia que contenga esa informacion, y no estar en el alumno. con left join, se traen un monton de registros que no existen en la otra tabla, que se ve es lo que querias, pero no lo que explicaste. La FK que detallaste al principio no tenia nada que ver y solo nos provoco confusion... Todo esto, es confuso..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola si quieres obtener las solicitudes que no tienen ningún alumno asociado, deberías utilizar un LEFT JOIN en lugar de un INNER JOIN. El LEFT JOIN devolverá todos los registros de la tabla de la izquierda (en este caso, solicitud), incluso si no hay coincidencias en la tabla de la derecha (en este caso, alumno).

Puedes intentar esto:

```
`SELECT f.id_solicitud,
  IF(COUNT(a.id_alumno) > 0, 'SI', 'NO') AS EXISTE
FROM solicitud f 
LEFT JOIN alumno a ON f.id_solicitud=a.id_solicitud
WHERE f.fecha_inicio = CURDATE() AND f.estado = 1
GROUP BY f.id_solicitud
HAVING EXISTE = 'NO'`
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, te lo agradezco, era lo que necesitaba. Logré traer los datos que necesitaba.

Comment: @SBK22 pero si [ya te habían dicho](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/610783/consulta-mysql-2-tablas#comment1076469_610783) que reemplaces `INNER JOIN` por `LEFT JOIN` y dijiste que "no te funcionó"... ¿Cuál es la diferencia?

Comment: Efectivamente, al igual me mi consulta solo mostraba 1 registro. La diferencia esta en la ultima parte de la consulta GROUP BY f.id_formulario_1
HAVING EXISTE = 'NO'

Comment: Esto se soluciona bastante mas facil con un exist, sin el join, y un union... pero es tan confuso el escenario... Igual esta solucion es correcta, para unas tablas que estarian mal...

Answer (score 1):

Para tener la consulta legible y entonces fácil de mantener, te aconsejo no usar un `JOIN`. Es que quieres seleccionar datos de tabla `solicitud`, entonces esta tabla esta en to `FROM`. Y tienes una condición respectivo a la tabla `alumno`. Condiciones deben estar en `WHERE`. Entonces:

```
SELECT s.id
FROM solicitud s
WHERE s.fecha_inicio = CURDATE()
AND s.estado = 1
AND NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT NULL
  FROM alumno a
  WHERE a.id_solicitud = s.id_solicitud
);
```

Si la id_solicitud no puede ser NULL en la tabla `alumno`, puedes usar `NOT IN`, que es un poco más simple:

```
SELECT s.id
FROM solicitud s
WHERE s.fecha_inicio = CURDATE()
AND s.estado = 1
AND s.id_solicitud NOT IN (SELECT a.id_solicitud FROM alumno a);
```

(`NOT IN` no funciona cuando la subconsulta produce NULLs.)

Siempre usa `[NOT] EXISTS`o `[NOT] IN` cuando quieres comprobar si existen datos congruentes en una tabla.

Comment: Gracias por responder, la primera consulta funciona correctamente.